# OpenGL - Cube is translating with with local location, not globally

Tags: java, opengl

In the LWJGL binding of OpenGL I am trying to make a cube that will be able to location, rotate and scale based on user input.  The rotation of the cube is meant to be based on an offset value, which is the distance of the cube from the point of rotation.

The only problem I am facing is that the location of the cube is set in relation to the cube's rotation when I want it to locate.  So if I rotate the cube 45 degrees on, say, the X-axis, changing the Y-location will make it locate at a 45 degree angle local to the cube when I want it to locate globally (straight down).

Please bear in mind that I am not very experienced in GL and am still getting used matrices and how they operate.

```
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(pivot.xPos + offsetX, -(pivot.yPos + offsetY + 24), pivot.zPos + offsetZ);
    glRotatef(rotX, 1.0F, 0F, 0F);
    glRotatef(rotY, 0F, 1.0F, 0F);
    glRotatef(rotZ, 0F, 0F, 1.0F);
    glTranslatef(-(pivot.xPos + offsetX), (pivot.yPos + offsetY + 24), -(pivot.zPos + offsetZ));

    // This is where the cube's location is set.  The units are multiplied by two and the Y-location is offset by 24.
    glTranslatef(((pivot.xPos + offsetX) * 2 + sizeX), (((pivot.yPos + offsetY) * 2) + sizeY) - 24, -((pivot.zPos + offsetZ) * 2 + sizeZ));

    glScalef(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    ... draws the cube
    glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you do the translation after the cube has already been rotated, which means that the translation is in the local coordinate system. Move the last `glTranslate` call just below `glPushMatrix` and you should get what you want.

Comment: Right answer.  It turns out I misdiagnosed my problem and have different issues, but I'll figure that out separately.